# HTTP Status 404 Not found The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i am trying to demo out the use of Model

i have a HelloWorldController.java file
[image]

Project Structure is like this:

[image]

servlet config seems fine to me:

```
<!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo" />

<!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/META-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

the MVC config for despatcher seems fine:

```
<!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

<!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

on execution

URl: http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-demo/processFormVersionTwo?studentName=Larry fails with 404 Not found

URL: http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-demo/processForm
strangely processForm mapping executes successfully with

[image]

i also checked the jsp file

[image]
---> looks fine

helloworld-form.jsp

[image]
---> looks fine

i am not sure why the

URL: http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-demo/processFormVersionTwo?studentName=Larry is giving 404 not found error.

Comment: try http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-demo/processFormVersionTwo
if enter the page, probably the problem is the parameter..

Comment: tried but seems to be some other issue

Answer (score 0):

okay i did, Project -> clean -> rebuild
if that did not worked for you, delete the server and add again and retried it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when i was building my project and war generated. So I was placing my war into webapps of apache tomcat server with this name ensurance-web.3.0.1.war, then I got the error. I fixed the problem changing the war name to ensurance.war and worked for me. As you know when you start up the tomcat server this will generate a folder with the name of the war, so I think the server is looking for this folder name but another was given.